# jQuery BlockUI Element Blocking showOverlay: false

Tags: jquery, jquery-blockui

I am  using JQuery BLOCKUI for Element Blocking

but it's showOverlay: false option is not working any idea ??

```
$("#MessageMOCKUP").block({ css: {
    border: 'none',
    padding: '15px',
    showOverlay: false,
    backgroundColor: '#000',
    '-webkit-border-radius': '10px',
    '-moz-border-radius': '10px',
    opacity: .5,
    color: '#fff'
}
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the options documentation of the [jQuery blockUI](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#options) , the showOverlay option is not included in the css option. **css** is only for the message that is used for blocking. If you need to access the css of the overlay that is added then **overlayCSS** contains those styles. You could modify the opacity and color of the overlay to make it appear as if it is not present.

If you use if outside the css block like the following then the overlay that is added on top of the element does not get added.

```
$("your_selector").block({            
    showOverlay: false
});
```

Let me know if you need more information.