# jQuery BlockUI Element blocking not working on Firefox

Tags: jquery, jquery-blockui

I am trying to block click on links using jQuery blockUI plugin. It's seems to be working fine everywhere, but, Firefox.

this is how it looks in **Chrome**
[image: blockUI element blocking in Chrome]

and this is how it looks in **FF**

[image: blockUI element blocking in FF]

Here is the javascript code I am using to block/unblock elements

```
function blockOptions(clsId)
{     
    console.log("block: "+clsId);
    if(clsId!='undefined'){
        var eleToBlock  = "a."+clsId;
        //console.log(id);
        j(eleToBlock).parent().block({message:null,showOverlay: true, css: { opacity: '.5',  backgroundColor: 'black',cursor: 'progress' } });
    }
}

function unblockOptions(clsId)
{
    console.log("unblock: "+clsId);
    if(clsId!='undefined'){
        var eleToBlock = "a."+clsId;
        j(eleToBlock).parent().unblock(); 
    }
}
```

and here is the HTML for this:

```
<ul class="left-tab">
    <li title=""><a class="tab-pic1" id="" title="" href="javascript:;">&nbsp;</a></li>
    <li title=""><a class="tab-pic2" id="" title="" href="javascript:;">&nbsp;</a></li>
    <li title="" style="position: relative;"><a class="tab-pic3" id="" title="" href="javascript:;">&nbsp;</a></li>
    <li title="" style="position: relative;"><a class="tab-pic4" id="optio" title="" href="javascript:;">&nbsp;</a></li>
    <li title=""><a class="tab-pic5" id="" title="" href="javascript:;">&nbsp;</a></li>
    <li title="" style="position: relative;"><a class="tab-pic6" id="" title="" href="javascript:;">&nbsp;</a></li>
</ul>
```

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?
I've also checked [Alok Swain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910212/jquery-blockui-element-blocking-showoverlay-false) answer, but, did not worked for me.

Comment: really, no body has faced similar problem... ? I am unable to fix the problem, if anyone know how to fix the problem or an alternative plug-in, please let me know...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `applyPlatformOpacityRules` option to `false` in the call to `block()`.

The BlockUI plugin turns off the opacity specifically on Firefox under Linux environments, for some bizarre performance reason.  It's mentioned briefly in the [FAQ](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#faq), but it's easy to miss.

Comment: yes, figured that out that it was problem with Firefox. anyway thanks for your response.

Comment: your solution did worked for me (with some other css hacks), thanks for your help :)